# parsing xml file with PLSQL

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have a problem parsing one xml file in PLSQL. I want to say that I have no problem with the code with some other xml files but especially with this one.
So I am waiting for some leads to what I should look at in this xml file that causes the problem.

Here is the code in PLSQL :

```
filename := 'name_of_my_file.xml';
myParser := DBMS_XMLPARSER.newParser;
ficContent := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.Read2Clob(directoryWhereToFindTheFile, filename , '0');
```

And here is the line where the problem occurs :

```
DBMS_XMLPARSER.parseBuffer(myParser,ficContent);
```

Oracle error :

```
ORA-06502 : PL/SQL : numeric or value error
```

Any idea about what I should look at ?

Note : I think I should add something else.

This specific xml file was written on two lines only (that caused some problems with the Read2Clob, the lines were too long). So I formatted it in an IDE to have a good xml file, and I use this one. No more problem reading the file so but this error occuring.

Comment: A sample of the "working" and "not-working" XML would be of great help.

Comment: The content is the same, it is just that the "not working" one has 2 lines and "working" one has one node on each line.(formatted)

Comment: I think you should use `PARSECLOB`, instead of `PARSEBUFFER` on the first place and this just might be your problem. In the current case, you're parsing VARCHAR2, which in the case of the "working" XML could be below the size limit of VARCHAR2(4k or 32k, depending) and on the other case - it just exceeds it, since you're anyway passing a CLOB, which gets implicitly cast to VARCHAR2.

Comment: Your thing works !!! put it as an answer I can validate, explaing to me when I should use parsebuffer and parseclob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments below the question:

Your code looks like this:

```
filename := 'name_of_my_file.xml';
myParser := DBMS_XMLPARSER.newParser;
ficContent := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.Read2Clob(directoryWhereToFindTheFile, filename , '0');
DBMS_XMLPARSER.parseBuffer(myParser,ficContent);
```

For the specification of `DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.Read2Clob` [[LINK]](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_xslpro.htm#i1006644):

**Syntax**

```
DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.READ2CLOB(
   flocation     IN   VARCHAR2,
   fname         IN   VARCHAR2,
   csid          IN   NUMBER:=0)
   RETURN CLOB;
```

On the other hand `DBMS_XMLPARSER.parseBuffer` accepts `VARCHAR2` as a second argument and you're passing a `CLOB` there, which is OK (it gets implicitly cast to `VARCHAR2`), as long as it fits the size of the `VARCHAR2` (which could range from `4k` to `32k` in bytes, depending on your DB version and configuration).

Now the `CLOB` size is `4 GB - 1` (4 Giga Bytes - 1), which is considerably more than the largest `VARCHAR2`.

And thus, apparently this solves the problem.

As to when to use `parseBuffer` or `parseClob` - I think you got the point. I would guess though, that `parseClob` calls (internally) `parseBuffer` for each portion of `4k` bytes it splits out of the `CLOB` it receives, but that's just a guess (I can't imagine they are using different code for the same thing, but hey, it happens with legacy stuff:-) ).

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Inside your **XML** file write the following lines of code after XML code-

```
<...XML code...>
BEGIN
FOR r IN (
  SELECT ExtractValue(Value(p),'/row/name/text()') as clo1
      ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/row/Address/State/text()') as col2
      ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/row/Address/City/text()') as col3
FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/person/row'))) p
) LOOP
-- do whatever you want 
END LOOP;
END;
```